# Conditional row formatting in kendo-ui grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid for displaying.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ReportModel>()
  .Name("myReport")
  .Columns(cols =>
    {
       columns.Bound(c => c.sNo).Title("S.No.");
       columns.Bound(c => c.particulars).Title("Particulars");
    }
  )
  .DataSource(ds => ds
     .Ajax()
     .PageSize(20)
     .Read(read => read.Action("myReportList","Reporting")
  )
  .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
)
```

I want the formatting of the row to change to bold if and only if the cell in the SNo column is an alphabet otherwise the formatting must be normal.

Help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to achieve that:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/style-rows-cells-based-on-data-item-values

> - Use a row template. This approach is suitable if you do not intend to apply hierarchy, grouping, editing, and frozen columns to the Grid.
> - Use a databound handler and iterate the table rows. This approach is suitable if you intend to customize all rows of the Grid.
> - Use a databound handler and iterate the data items. This approach is suitable if you intend to customize only part of the Grid rows.

Comment: How does it not help?  What have you tried?  Here is the demo from the link in the answer that adds an "sNo" column with various values and uses all 3 techniques to make the lines with string values bold and big and lines with number values normal: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/Upusu

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.sNo)
    .ClientTemplate("<strong> #=DateOfService#</strong>")
    .Title("S.No.")
```

Comment: Hi Dwhitz, i have formatted but strong tag convert to bold in this editor so i had explained in next line.If you need any help mail me on my personal email id frfreelancer.amankumar@gmail.com, Thanks & Regards Aman